# How to revert changes to css made by javascript

Tags: javascript, css, string, html

So I have a button that toggles a simple dark theme for my web app.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="dark_mode()">Dark Mode ON</button>
```

Once the user clicks it will activate this function in javascript.

```
function dark_mode() {
    document.body.style.background = "#2C2F33";}
```

This will only change the background. I am wondering if the user clicks the button a second time it will revert the changes made by the function. (i.e toggle on/off) Thanks for the time and help in advance!

Comment: What's the background meant to be normally? `#FFFFFF` (white)?

Comment: You can use data tag in the button to keep current theme and switch accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make it by toggling CSS class, it is more flexible solution

```js
function dark_mode() {
  document.body.classList.toggle('dark-mode')
}
```

```css
.dark-mode {
  background: #2C2F33
 }
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="dark_mode()">Dark Mode ON</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just check and change the style using a ternary operator:

```
function dark_mode() {
    document.body.style.background = document.body.style.background == "#2C2F33" ? "#FFFFFF" : "#2C2F33";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `data` tags to track current theme :

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="dark_mode(this);" data-dark-theme="on" >Dark Mode ON</button>
```

JS :

```
function dark_mode(ctrl) {
var darkTheme = ctrl.getAttribute("data-dark-theme"); 
  if(darkTheme== "on"){
    ctrl.setAttribute("data-dark-theme", "off"); 
    document.body.style.background = "#2C2F33";
    ctrl.innerHTML  = "Dark Mode OFF";
  }
  else {
    ctrl.setAttribute("data-dark-theme", "on"); 
    document.body.style.background = "#FFFFFF";
    ctrl.innerHTML  = "Dark Mode ON";
  }
}
```

[Working demo](https://jsbin.com/puhalabiza/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Use [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes#javascript_access) to interact with `data-*` attributes: set with `ctrl.dataset.darkTheme = true`, read with `ctrl.dataset.darkTheme`. (`kebab-case` is automatically converted to `camelCase`.)

Answer (score 2):

If the user clicks again, the function is simply called again. So, after the first click there are no more changes.

A better way would be to assign your dark mode styles to a class, say "btn--dark-mode" and then use js to toggle that class:

```js
function dark_mode() {
document.querySelector('#dark-mode-toggle').classList.toggle('dark-mode'); // ie9+ only
}
```

```css
.btn--dark-mode {
  background-color: #2C2F33;
}
```

```html
<button id="dark-mode-toggle" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="dark_mode()">Dark Mode ON</button>
```

This will apply the class or take it off depending on whether it is already there.

Comment: This will add .dark-mode class to button because you are querying `document.querySelector('#dark-mode-toggle')`